# Finding the difference between two data-frames

Tags: python, pandas

[image]I'm trying to find the largest income difference between male and female workers. But I'm not sure how to implement the code. I need some assistance.

```
aa=industries.F_weekly.max()
bb=industries.M_weekly.max()
cc = (nf.loc[nf['M_weekly'] == bb]) - (nf.loc[nf['F_weekly'] == aa])
cc.max()
cc.min()
```

Comment: Please add 2 sample dataframes to show the format of your data. This will really help users who are trying to provide an answer. It will also make this question more relevant/useful to future users who come to this post.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "largest income difference"? Shouldn't you be looking at the max(M_weekly_ - min(F_weekly) if it is what it sounds like?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your Dataframe is called df.
First, calculate the absolute value of salary difference, then print max. This can also be done in one line.

```
df['salary_delta'] = (df['M_weekly'] - df['F_weekly']).abs()
print(max(df['salary_delta']))
```

In case you want to find the row where salary difference is the highest then try:

```
df.loc[df['salary_delta'].idxmax()]
```